# Github actions:Build and Push docker image iam policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, amazon-iam, amazon-ecr

Hello I am using Github actions AWS EC2 and IAM policy for building and pushing docker image. however i am getting the following error:

> Error: buildx failed with: error: failed to solve: unexpected status:
> 403 Forbidden.

The iam policy I am using is as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:PutImage"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Not sure what i should do in order for this to work

Comment: I wanted to clarify few things, you are using  github actions to push to ecr? or are you using using ec2 for pushing images to ecr?

Comment: Unfortunately [Amazon's docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/image-push.html#image-push-iam) are incorrect (I've left feedback with the correction on that page). I put the correct policy in my answer below.

Comment: the docs are still not fixed

Answer (score 6):

You have to include `ecr:BatchGetImage` for the image in question. The complete policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:PutImage"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ecr:region:111122223333:repository/repository-name"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```